# Idiomatic Approach to Filter Struct Field - Rust

Tags: rust

I frequently need to find then remove something from some `Vec<>` type struct field. Does the following represent an idiomatic approach to doing this?

````rust
struct Roster{
    names: Vec<String>
    //..
}

impl Roster{
    pub fn remove_name(&mut self, name: &str){
        //are both of these lines necessary or could they be reduced to a single linge?
        let to_keep =  self.current.names.clone().into_iter().filter(|n|*n != name).collect();
        self.current.names = keep
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut r = Roster{
        vec!["P1".to_string(), "P2".to_string()],
    }
    r.remove_name("P1")
}
```
````

Comment: The question is now answered and thus there's little point in closing it, but your question is skirting the rules a bit. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] and note we don't do well with hypothetical and stub code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method that directly does what you want: [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain).

```rust
    pub fn remove_name(&mut self, name: &str){
        self.current.names.retain(|n| n != name);
    }
```

If `retain` didn't exist, it would also be possible to write what you're currently doing without `clone`ing the entire vector, using either `std::mem::take` or `Vec::drain` to remove the data from `self` temporary so that you can `.into_iter()` it.